# Выравнивание по вертикали в <li>

Tags: html, css

Решил написать разметку для сайта, тематика: "Онлайн буклет одежды".

Столкнулся с проблемой: в теге `li` нельзя выровнять по центру по вертикали, только по горизонтали.

Прочитал кучу туторов и все как один говорят: установить `display: inline-table;`  и `vertical-align: middle;`, но ничего не работает.

В чём может быть проблема?

```css
.Content{
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 width: 600px;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 0 20px 20px 20px;
 float: left;
}
.categories{
 float: left;
 border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
 background-color: #f7f7f7;
 width: 200px;
 height: 800px;
}
.CategoryReference{
 font-size: 14pt;
 margin: auto;
 color: #04c;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ol {
 padding: 0px;
 padding-top: 18px;
 list-style: none;
}
li{
 display: inline-table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 36px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #38546F;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#resourceLinks a:visited{
  color: #04c;
}
a:visited {
  color: #5a7bad;
}
a:link {
  color: #04c;
}
a:hover{
 color: #a5c3fe;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new 1.css">
 </head>
 <body style="background-image: url(BGI.jpg);">
  <div style="width: 800px; height: 1000px; margin: auto;">
   <div class="categories">
    <ol style="margin: auto;">
     <li>
      <a class="CategoryReference" href="vk.com">Рубашки</a>
     </li>

     <li>
      <a class="CategoryReference">Блузки</a>
     </li>


     <li>
      <a class="CategoryReference">Топы</a>
     </li>


     <li>
      <a class="CategoryReference">Футболки</a>
     </li>
    </ol>
   </div>
   <div class="Content">
   
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так.
`display: inline-table` и `vertical-align` убрать и добавить:

```
 li:before {
         content: "";
         display: inline-block;
         height: 100%;
         vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Comment: Классный способ!

Answer (score 0):

Уберите display: inline-table. И добавьте вашему тегу a, который вложен в li свойство line-height: 36px; это выровняет по вертикали, т.к. интерлиньяж будет равен высоте li. Код:

```
.categories li a {
    line-height: 36px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Роман за правку. Пользуюсь сайтом с телефона - невозможно оформить код в мобильной версии